Please make browser auto-saving in real time
Spent a long time typing out a really beautiful question. Browser froze and crashed. Reopened Stack Exchange. The auto-save feature is where the question was like twenty minutes ago. No motivation to retype it.
Please communicate to Stack Exchange people to make auto-saving in real-time.

I'm not sure there's much pull here at PhilSE on what goes on over there.

You might try a browser extension like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/form-history-control/ . (I cannot vouch for the safety or efficacy of this extension)

Explanation for current behavior: Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting -> "We save drafts automatically for all new answers and new questions once every 45 seconds." ... unless your internet connection is down in the middle.

I've found Notepad++ to be very useful in safely typing out and managing comments (not answers) before posting them here. I can't remember the last time my browser crashed, but I have accidentally closed a tab on occasion. If you want something with Markdown support, I'd probably recommend Obsidian, which I started using more recently. Although I do already use those frequently for other purposes.
